# c++ return element gives access violation on line without code

Tags: c++, class, access-violation

When I am trying to return an element from my array, my program crashes and it says access violation in visual studio 2012. I don't know how that's possible because I initialized the array and allocated memory for it. I have a class Tweet where I initialize tweets. I also have a class indexelement which puts tweets with the same hashtag in an array.
Header of indexelement:

```
#ifndef INDEXELEMENT_H
#define INDEXELEMENT_H
#include "Tweet.h"
#include <string>

class IndexElement {
private:
    std::string hashtag;
    int size;
    Tweet* array;
    int memory;
public:
    IndexElement(std::string tag);
    IndexElement(const IndexElement& copy);
// Default constructor om makkelijker te kunnen werken in de klasse HashTagIndexer.
    IndexElement();
    ~IndexElement();
public:
    std::string getHashTag() const;
    void addTweet(Tweet tweet);
    int getNumTweets() const;
    Tweet getTweet(int i) const;
};
#endif
```

Header of tweet:

```
#ifndef TWEET_H
#define TWEET_H
#include <string>
class Tweet{
private:
    int id;
    std::string tweeter;
    time_t date;
    std::string tweet;
    std::string* tags;
    int num_tags;
public:
    Tweet(int id, std::string tweeter, time_t date, std::string tweet, std::string* tags, int     num_tags);
    Tweet();
    ~Tweet();
public:
    int getID() const;
    std::string getTweeter() const;
    time_t getDate() const;
    std::string getTweet() const;
    int getNumHashtags() const;
    std::string getHashtag(int i) const;
};
#endif
```

I made some test, but it gives me an error at this test:

```
bool addTweetIndexElementTest()
{
    IndexElement a("#test");
    string tags[1] = {"#test"};
    Tweet t1(1,"lennart",0,"dit is een teststring",tags,1);
    a.addTweet(t1);
    cout << a.getTweet(0).getID(); // program crashes here!!

}
```

the getTweet implementation:

```
Tweet IndexElement::getTweet(int i) const{
    if(i>=size){
        return Tweet();
    } else {
        cout << array[i].getID();  
        return array[i];  // this actually works (i.e. it don't crashes on this line)
    }
}  // when I set a breakpoint on this line en press continue the program crashes. Don't know why because there's no code and the program also doesn't go to the destructor so it also couldn't be that.
```

Just to be sure, here is my destructor:

```
IndexElement::~IndexElement(){
    delete[] array;
}

Tweet::~Tweet(){
    delete[] tags;
}
```

I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: Looks like it's crashing in the Tweet() deconstructor.  What does it do?

Comment: it just deletes the tags array:

Check question I putted it overthere

Comment: You pass to `Tweet t1` a pointer to `tags`, which is a local variable and dies at the end of `addTweetIndexElementTest`.

Comment: @Eques Is `tags` correctly initialized to `NULL` or a validly allocated pointer by all constructors?

Comment: Look up the 'rule of three'. And to make your life easier, learn how to use `std::vector`.

Comment: if you are deleting tags in the deconstructor, make sure that Tweet::Tweet() is initializing to NULL or creating the pointer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter in is a pass by value, which is a local copy on the stack:

```
void addTweet(Tweet tweet); // tweet will be freed when leaving the function
```

Do either of these instead:

```
void addTweet(const Tweet& tweet); // assumes there is a copy constructor for Tweet
void addTweet(Tweet* tweet);       // will not retain the Tweet object
```

Unless you are doing this as an exercise, I'd strongly advice you to use std::vector rather than raw pointers for your lists.

Comment: Passing in by value is the correct way. Passing a pointer or reference to local variable `Tweet t1' is the real problem.